# Why is this statement in PHP returning a syntax error?

Tags: php, curl, syntax, get

I have a PHP file that uses the cURL library and everything is fine up until this statement, which returns a syntax error:

```
$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

I get the syntax error: `Expecting Statement`, however the code does indeed finish executing. The program is supposed to return a JSON file.

Any ideas on why this is? I'm running PHP Interpreter v. 5.6

The rest of the code:

```
<?php

$uri = 'https://example.com';

$headers = 'Authentication info...';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array($headers));
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // Where syntax error occurs

if ($httpStatus != 200) {
    echo 'error calling webservice, status is:' . $httpStatus;
    exit(-1);
}

echo $json_response;
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: Change `$curl_setopt(...)` to `curl_setopt(...)`.

Comment: Again, typo on my part. I fixed it.

Comment: Please post the *full* error message.

Comment: It simply is `Expecting Statement` and only within the IDE. There is no error at runtime, as the code finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt is a function. $status also does not exist.

Comment: Typo on my part, that's now been fixed. Your answer doesn't really clear anything up for me. I understand `curl_setopt` is a function, but `$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` is where I am generating the syntax error. Could you please update your answer?

Comment: Hmm, in that case I'm not exactly sure. I stepped through your code and got no such errors on my end

Answer (score 0):

curl_getinfo will return something when the curl_exec succeeds, so use it in a syntax like this:

```
if(!curl_errno($curl)) {
$httpStatus = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
}
```

Comment: When I do this, my syntax error switches to the line containing `json_response = curl_exec($curl);`